# How to edit keyboard.conf from another system

Tags: keyboard, dconf

I made the mistake of editing the file

**etc/x11/xorg.conf.d/keyboard.conf**

and now my laptop won't start.

I try to edit the file from another system installed in another partition and it tells me that I don't have the necessary permissions.

Is it possible that you can edit the file and leave its original values? How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Explain it a bit better: "from another system" How? ssh? mounted the disk inside the other system?  do you have a `#` as a prompt?  do you use a normal user? "and now my laptop won't start." that should not be a reason though. You should be able to get to grub, drop to root/rescue and edit from there. The same is possible using a live session. ALL of those are done as "root" and will not complain about permissions so I do not really get why you do ... and probably are doing it in away that is more difficult than it needs to be (I hope :))

Comment: You must be root to edit files on drives you are not having permissions as normal user. Easiest probably will be to mount a live Ubuntu session, and do the edit from there. You could then immediately see how that file looks in the live session, and copy it over to your system partition, overwriting the one you broke.